# Using AES in Objective-c

Tags: objective-c, ios, encryption, nsstring, aes

I'm looking for ways to encrypt and decrypt NSStrings with a user defined keyword in Objective-C. I found this in a different Stack Overflow post:[AES256 in objective-c](http://pastie.org/426530).

How can one go about using these methods, I'm fairly new to Objective-C programming. How can I do this? Are there any tutorials on this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a category on NSData--  it adds `AES256EncryptWithKey:` and `AES256DecryptWithKey:` to the methods supported by NSData.

So, to encrypt a string, you would first convert your string into an NSData object (using [`dataUsingEncoding:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html) on the string), then call `AES256EncryptWithKey` on the NSData object you get from `dataUsingEncoding`.